# Data categorization

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp, multilabel-classification, nltk

I'm using Google API to categorize and predict problems with laptops (Hardware, Software, Network, Customer satisfaction, No reason). I inserted my training data and categories are very well evaluated and predicted. 
Training data only uses 5 main categories as it comes from free text and being specific requires some manual work.
Now I want to go a level deeper and tag these categories: Example. Laptop was returned because Display was cracked:
Hardware category was defined already, but I have a dictionary where I can also look for the word "Display". Example:

```
Hardware:
   Display:
      failure: True
   Info:
      Physical_damage: Display cracked
```

Unable to install Skype:

```
Software:
   Applications:
      Skype:
       failure: True
   Info:
      Description: Unable to upgrade
```

I want to categorize first using main categories and after main category is chosen, look into my text for possible options from a bag of words (Example: `{"display": ["screen", "display", "monitor"] }, {"applications", "skype","office","adobe","spotify"}`

Should I run these in 2 stages? Any recommended pattern or solution?

Comment: Somehow I am not able to get a clear understanding of what you are trying to achieve. I mean can you specify what data does Google API provide you and what results you get after first iteration of clustering and so on.

Comment: I edited the question